# Using image_tag inside rails engine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image, asset-pipeline, rails-engines

Why doesn't `image_tag("cheese.png")` load the image in my view (inside `my_engine`), when it is located in `assets/images/my_engine/cheese.png` ?

Answer (score 0):

@Simrayz - I'd need to see more of your directory structure to fully understand, but in general the image pathing in rails isn't dependent on your view structure. It's dependent on the assets image directory structure.

So if you have assets/images/my_engine/cheese.png you can access it with the path my_engine/cheese.png from any view, regardless of the directory structure of your view files.

Comment: `my_engine` was generated with `rails plugin new my_engine --mountable`, and is mounted in a standard rails application. In my view, inside `app/views/my_engine/pages/index.html.erb`, I try to load the image by writing `image_tag("cheese.png")`, but no image shows. I have also tried with `image_tag("my_engine/cheese.png")`, still no image. If I write a normal img tag, `<img src="assets/my_engine/cheese.png">` the image is loaded, which means that it is added to assets, but the helper method can't find it :/